# How do i show another output below the first?

Tags: android, kotlin

the 1st image

[image]

so this the 1st data, then when i try to input another data

2nd pic

[image]

how to show another input under the 1st input data?
here's my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity5">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/nama_matkul" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/nama_matkul"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/pilih_matkul" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Nilai" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/fill_nilai"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/fill_nilai"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:hint="@string/edtx"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dang"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dang" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tampilkan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="379dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:maxLines="9"/>
```

and my kt

```
       class MainActivity5 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5)

        val nama_matkul= findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.nama_matkul)
        val fill_nilai = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.fill_nilai)
        val dang = findViewById<Button>(R.id.dang)
        val tampilkan = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tampilkan)

        dang.setOnClickListener {

            tampilkan.text= "mata kuliah :"+nama_matkul.selectedItem.toString()+"\n Nilai :"+fill_nilai.text


        }
    }
}
```

and sorry for poor english